# Exclude object by date

Tags: python

I have a JSON file with multiple objects and array including dates. And I'd like to select an object if one of its key value date is before 2019.

```
for b in data:
    results = b['results']

    for a in results:
        if not results == []:
            date_pyt = a["auction_datetime"]
            date_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_pyt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            maxdate = datetime(2018, 12, 31).date()

            prices = [a["price_int_eu"] for a in results if maxdate >= date_datetime]
            prices = [a for a in prices if a is not None]

     print(prices)
```

My input:

```
{("id": 1,
 "results": []},
{"id": 2,
"results": [
            {
                "auction_datetime": "2019-06-15",
                "price_int_eu": 13325
            },
            {
                "auction_datetime": "2018-08-25",
                "price_int_eu": 5523
            },
            {
                "auction_datetime": "2017-04-29",
                "price_int_eu": 8309
            },
            {
                "auction_datetime": "2016-10-20",
                "price_int_eu": null
            }
        ]}
```

The output:
`[13325, 5523, 8309]`
In theory, the `13325` musn't be printed.

Comment: It's an error, it was before 2019, I edited my question.

Comment: The `if not results == []` test is redundant, the `for` loop will not execute the loop body when `results` is empty.

Comment: You are executing your `prices = [...]` loop *for each element in `results`, so you don't need the `for a in results` loop either. You are filtering all `results` values with the date from one of the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking the date from one of the elements in `results`, then filtering *all* results on that date. So if the current item date fits (is before 2019), then all elements are selected, and for the next element, you do the same test again. Each time you recreate the `prices` list with the outcome for the current element in `a` so in the end only the last outcome remains.

You need to use a single loop. Either use a list comprehension, or a full `for` loop, not both.

Using a simple loop:

```
maxdate = datetime(2018, 12, 31).date()
prices = []
for b in data:
    results = b['results']
    for a in results:
        date_pyt = a["auction_datetime"]
        date_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_pyt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        if date <= max_date and a["price_int_eu"] is not None:
            prices.append(a["price_int_eu"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each result's auction date with 2019 explicitly:

```
from datetime import date

def get_prices_before_year(data, year):
    prices_before_year= []

    for b in data:
        results = b["results"]
        for result in results:
            auction_date = date(*map(int, result["auction_datetime"].split("-")))
            if auction_date.year < year and result["price_int_eu"]:
                prices_before_year.append(result["price_int_eu"])

    return prices_before_year

def main():
    data = [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "results": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "auction_datetime": "2019-06-15",
                            "price_int_eu": 13325
                        },
                        {
                            "auction_datetime": "2018-08-25",
                            "price_int_eu": 5523
                        },
                        {
                            "auction_datetime": "2017-04-29",
                            "price_int_eu": 8309
                        },
                        {
                            "auction_datetime": "2016-10-20",
                            "price_int_eu": None
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]

    print(get_prices_before_year(data, 2019))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
[5523, 8309]
```